# Add class to parent div if any of the child elements has a certain class, remove if not (jQuery or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selections of dropdowns each with several buttons styled as checkboxes. When one of the buttons is clicked, it gets the class "active". What I would like to do is to add class "active" to the parent dropdown if any of the child elements (buttons) has class active (either with jQuery or Javascript).

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-checkboxes">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle">Brand</div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" data-filter-group="brand">
        <button class="control-condition custom-checkbox" data-toggle=".volvo"><span class="checkmark"></span>Volvo</button>
        <button class="control-condition custom-checkbox" data-toggle=".bmw"><span class="checkmark"></span>BMW</button>
        <button class="control-condition custom-checkbox" data-toggle=".fiat"><span class="checkmark"></span>Fiat</button>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I've tried**

```
$(".control-condition").click(function () {
    if ($('.dropdown-menu:has(.active)')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

This adds class "active" to the parent dropdown just as it should, but it does not remove the class when the buttons are "unchecked" (no class active).

Any advice or guidance would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: It is unclear which element exactly you want to toggle active on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with vanilla Javascript, as in 99.99% of cases.

```js
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-checkboxes .control-condition')];

document.querySelector('.dropdown-checkboxes')
  .addEventListener('click',
  ({target}) => {
    if (buttons.includes(target.closest('button'))) {
      target.closest('button').classList.toggle('active');
      target
        .closest('.dropdown') // get the parent you need
        .classList[buttons.some(btn => 
          btn.classList.contains('active')) // if any button has class active
          ? 'add' // add .active
          : 'remove' // otherwise remove .active
        ]
        ('active');
    }
  }
)
```

```css
.checkmark::before {
  content: '✓';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}

button.active>.checkmark::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.dropdown {
  transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown.active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown dropdown-checkboxes">
  <div class="dropdown-toggle">Brand</div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" data-filter-group="brand">
    <button class="control-condition custom-checkbox" data-toggle=".volvo"><span class="checkmark"></span>Volvo</button>
    <button class="control-condition custom-checkbox" data-toggle=".bmw"><span class="checkmark"></span>BMW</button>
    <button class="control-condition custom-checkbox" data-toggle=".fiat"><span class="checkmark"></span>Fiat</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should mention the polyfills needed for this to work cross browser. Considering jQuery is already used in the project, I'd say writing 3 times the amount of code only to need polyfills for it to work is a blunder. Note it also only works on the first `.dropdown-checkboxes` found in DOM. Another small problem with it is it doesn't toggle when you're clicking on the actual checkmark.

Comment: Honestly, jQuery has become somewhat of a *no-go* in modern web development. Everybody and their brother is aiming to get rid of the jQuery dependency. jQuery has had its use for many, many years. Those are over, imo. Same is true for lodash and underscore.

Comment: I kindly disagree. When used correctly, it's quite powerfull, concise and useful. The cases where I actually use it are quite few nowadays and I try to stay away from it, but when already in the project (or when it makes sense to include it - i.e: fast prototyping) i see it for what it is: a smart and powerfull tool. It probably ***is*** too flexible and allows people to use it wrongly. I'd say that's its biggest flaw.

Comment: I haven't had a single reason in the past 3 years for using jQuery except jQuery datatables. What exactly do you consider it useful for? Even for fast prototyping, I'm that much faster with vanilla Javascript.

Comment: In reality, I only use it when prototyping with Bootstrap (because it's already there) - allows me to make fairly complex prototypes in less than 2 hours. However, over the past year I've mostly prototyped with Vue (and VueBootstrap, which are both jQuery free). Also, there was this very specific case where I found it quite useful for producing large amounts of HTML for emails (considering the very specific requirements of HTML in emails). But I sometimes miss jQuery's out-of-the-box cross-browser compatibility, when writing vanilla code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$('.dropdown-menu:has(.active)')` will always be `true`, you'll have to change the check to something like this:

```
if ($('.dropdown-menu:has(.active)').length) { ... }
```

But it will be more appropriate to use `.toggleClass` in this case, here is an example:

```
$(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('active', !!$('.dropdown-menu:has(.active)').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.hasClass()`

```
$(".control-condition").click(function () {
    if (!$('.dropdown-menu').hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

But note there is a problem with your logic. You check if `.dropdown-menu` has the class `active` but the `active` class is being set on `dropdown-checkboxes` because of this `$(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');`

So either change `$(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');` to `$(this).parent().addClass('active');`

 or change `$('.dropdown-menu').hasClass("active")` to `$('.dropdown-checkboxes').hasClass("active")`

**Demo**

```js
$(".control-condition").click(function () {
    if (!$('.dropdown-menu').hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown dropdown-checkboxes">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle">Brand</div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" data-filter-group="brand">
        <button class="control-condition custom-checkbox" data-toggle=".volvo"><span class="checkmark"></span>Volvo</button>
        <button class="control-condition custom-checkbox" data-toggle=".bmw"><span class="checkmark"></span>BMW</button>
        <button class="control-condition custom-checkbox" data-toggle=".fiat"><span class="checkmark"></span>Fiat</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.dropdown').on('click', '.control-condition', function() {
  const parent = $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu');
  parent.toggleClass(
    'active',
    $('.control-condition.active', parent).is('.control-condition.active')
  );
})
```

If you want the `active` class on `.dropdown`, change `.dropdown-menu` to `.dropdown`.

This will work cross-browser, on all current and future children of `.dropdown-menu` (because it binds to the dropdown).

If you want something that works for current and any `.dropdown` not yet added in DOM, change first line to:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.dropdown .control-condition', function() {
```

Note on event delegation: delegating a large amount of events to `'body'` can and will affect the page performance. Do not delegate to `'body'` events with high frequency, such as `scroll` or `mousemove`. Read more on [event-performance](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate trought all the elements with the dropdown class, and if it has some active element make it active (First remove all active class from the parent if not it will be duplicated):

```
$(".control-condition").click(function () {
  $( "dropdown-menu" ).each(function( index ) {
     var element = $(this)
     // first we remove the class in case it already exist
     element.removeClass('active')
     // then we check if element with class active exist inside the menu
     if(element.find('.active').length == 1){
       element.addClass('active')
     }
  });
});
```